# ASP.NET and Vue Integration

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, vuejs2, integration

I have an existing ASP.NET project and I need to integrate Vue.Js into the ASP.NET HTML so I can use Vue features.

When Vue Instance is loaded my ASP.NET HTML wipes out and it makes sense because Vue takes over the `'el'` and render on it, but I need to maintain my ASP.NET HTML.

Here is how I integrated Vue in the project:

1. Initialized a new Vue project using VUE CLI (used Vue2).
2. Built the project with an empty Vue instance (without rendering anything).
3. Copied the built (js only) files to the ASP.NET project and used `<script>` tags to import them.

Did I do something wrong? how can I maintain ASP.NET HTML?

I don't want to use a CDN.

I appreciate your help people,

Thank you all.

Comment: Vue will [mount](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app) to whatever element you specify when you create the Vue instance.  It will only affect the element you mount it to.  Mount it to a new element that isn't involved in your ASP.NET HTML.

Comment: but in this case i can't  use Vue binding feature inside ASP HTMl, can i?

Comment: If you want Vue to have some control over it, you'll need to redo the ASP HTML inside Vue.